# Bootbox callback not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I'm trying to use this:

```
 $('#delete').live('click',function(){
                var result;
                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(response){
                        result=response;
                });
                alert(result);
                return result;
            });
```

But when the button is clicked:

Alert is shown first and only after that bootbox shows confirm dialog.

I want to return the response , but if i do it from within call back it doesn't work because it returns response from callback but not $('#devicedelete').live('click',function(){});

Btw i'm trying to submit a form basing on response. So if i return 'true' form will be submitted, else if it returns 'false', form wont be submitted.

Please check this: http://pastebin.com/9H3mxE9Y

I have one big table with checkboxes for each row, users select checkboxes and click on any of the buttons 'delete' , 'copy'  etc and form should be submitted.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialog is async, you can prevent the default action right away, and then call the submit if the user accepts. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ty5Wc/3/

```
$('#delete').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (response) {        
        if(response) {
            $('#form').submit();
        }
    });
});
$('#form').submit(function () {
    //do your validation or whatever you need to do before submit
});
```

Edit: After talking more with OP, he also wanted to pass button value in the query string, my solution for that is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ty5Wc/5/

```
$('#delete').on('click', function (e, confirmed) {
    if (!confirmed) {
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $('#delete').trigger('click', true);
            }
        });
    }
});
$('#form').submit(function (e) {
    //do your validation or whatever you need to do before submit
});
```

Comment: Hi, I want to return the value of the response , response will be either 'true' or 'false'. but if i do it from within call back it doesn't work because it returns response from callback.

Comment: This is happening on click, what would it be returning it to? Anyway, instead of doing whatever you want to do after it returns, just make those into functions and call those functions from within the callback.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can prevent the form submission with `preventDefault()`

Comment: I had to use submit event in a different function. So if this click event returns true, and form 'submit' event returns true, then form will be submitted, so i can't use e.preventDefault();  for click , just have to return true or false.

Comment: It sounds like you have two listeners for essentially the same event, why not combine them? I think I'd have to see more context to be of more help

Comment: It still doesn't provide me enough to be of more help, I'd need to see the dom this is working on at least. Is the form submitted with a click on `devicedelete`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30649/discussion-between-sash-and-smerny)

Comment: I dedicated quite some hours to a defect regarding bootbox.confirm. This worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Perdomoff - no problem, fun to get a comment on something from 3 years ago that i don't remember :p