# Rails delete link call from javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootbox

With rails I can do this:

```
<%= link_to("Delete", product, 
            :method => :delete, 
            data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?.'}
            id: 'discard_btn') %>
```

and I know that when the click is received, a standard javascript confirm dialog will ask the 'Are you sure?' question sending the request if an OK is clicked.

I want to change this plain dialog with a beautiful Bootbox confirm dialog with the same behavior.  I tried to do this:

```
$('#employee_discard').click(function(e){
  bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    // How to send the delete request from this callback?
  });
  // Prevent the request to be sent.  This works/  
  return false;
});
```

But my problem is that Bootbox uses callbacks to handle its events and just writing a return true inside the callback will not work.

How can I send a delete request from javascript?

Comment: The click handler had already returned false. In the callback you test the `result` value then either [`$.post(delete_url, data, callback_func)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) or submit a form `$(form).submit()`. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759727/bootbox-callback-not-working-properly?rq=1) explains the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @Jasen  Your answer reference solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: "/products/1"
})
```

And in the controller you need to add a response in js format

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render "something.js.erb" }
end
```

Finally, the something.js.erb will be executed. For example, you can refresh the current page

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: Gracias @Diego.  I finally solved my problem with jasen reference, but your answer makes sense, and I'll accept it.